# How to create Crown OnClick event on WearOS?

Tags: java, android, wear-os

i've just created a WearOS Launcher and i would like to achieve Watchface/AppList switch using the crown/home button OnClick event.
How could i do this? The app has already overwritten the system launcher so it behaves as a launcher mostly.

Comment: Override `onNewIntent()` and see if you get an `Intent` when you press HOME while your launcher activity is in the foreground.